# What is purpose of done in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS v1.2.13 there is a following instruction:

```
var when = function(value, callback, errback, progressback) {
  var result = defer(),
    done;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

does anybody knows for what done in the mentioned source code stands?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. `done` should be a function, not a keyword. Angular _can't_ add keywords--they can only add functions to javascript. Keywords are reserved words native to the language.

Comment: I didn't say that done used as keyword

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy — Your question title asks "What is keyword done".

Comment: Did you notice a comma (`,`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same as:

```
  var result = defer();
  var done;
```

`done` is just another variable

Comment: Do you really think this question deserves an answer?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a keyword, it is an identifier.

It is used, here, in a variable declaration (the `var` statement that starts on the previous line).

You can declare multiple variables in a single statement with `var foo, bar, baz;`.

The variable is then used [several lines later](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.x/src/ng/q.js#L455).

Comment: Do you really think this question deserves an answer?